# How to scan ALL mail via Gmail API?

Tags: gmail, oauth-2.0, imap, gmail-imap

After I OAuth my google account I can connect to it via the IMAP protocol. Listing folders lists all the "labels" plus "[Gmail]" which isn't selectable.

Is there any way to list ALL mail and/or at least get into the trash? Also what about archived - those don't show up in the INBOX folder

I did some digging around and tried this:
var_dump($storage->getFolders('[Gmail]'));

which doesn't list anything... but this does:
var_dump($storage->getFolders('[Gmail]/Trash'));

How can I list all those folders

Answer (score 0):

**[Gmail]/All Mail** contains all of your messages in Gmail, including your sent and archived messages. Any messages that you see in your inbox will also appear in the **[Gmail]/All Mail** folder.